# Should a service access other services or just repositories?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

As an example, the customer service has a method that cancels a particular order for that customer:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService<Customer>
{
     public void CancelOrder(int orderNo) 
     {
         //customerRepository here...
     }
}
```

Then, another service used for batch processing can also cancel multiple orders:

```
public class BatchService : IBatchService
{
     public void CancelOrders(params int[] orderNos) 
     {
         //What here?
     }
}
```

The code for cancelling the customer's order is located in the `CustomerService`. Should the `BatchService` call `CustomerService.CancelOrder` or should it just use the customer repository too?

Comment: That's subjective. Choose what is best for you.

Comment: Everything is subjective, other thing is if you should write same repo logic twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write the cancelling logic twice. Where you have it is up to you, but given your current structure, I'd inject ICustomerService into BatchService. So class could look something like

```
public class BatchService : IBatchService
{
    public ICustomerService<Customer> CustService { get; set; }

    public void CancelOrders(params int[] orderNos)
    {
        foreach (int orderNo in orderNos)
            CustService.CancelOrder(orderNo);
    }
}
```